# Browse Folders On Another Server in WebForms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to browse folders on another server in an ASP.NET WebForm. The IIS is v6.2. The following code works when run outside of IIS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            window.location.href = "file://192.168.147.37/Archive/";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The ASP.NET function I'm using to do this is:

```
Response.Redirect("file://192.168.147.37/Archive/")
```

This returns a blank page or error page depending on settings for web.config or the web page. The HTML example above returns a blank page on IIS. Is it possible to list folder contents in IIS on a WebForm?

Thanks

Comment: Your use case is not clear, you are attempting to use the [File Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/jj710207(v=vs.85)) on a webpage which is not really a web protocol, maybe read [Directory Browse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse) configuration for IIS.

Comment: I've enabled directory browsing and I'm still getting a blank page.